# First Order Logic - unsatisfiable set of formulas

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, satisfiability

I know what is an unsatisfiable set of formulas in first order logic and I'm studying how to prove the unsatisfiability.

What I don't understand, I'm sorry a think as an engineer, is what get in practice when I prove that set of formulas is unsatisfiable. Can you intuitively explain this to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be *unsatisfiable* means the impossibility to find an interpretation that simultaneously satisfies **all** the formulas of the set.

A typical case will be the set:

> $\{ p(x), \lnot p(x) \}$.

There is no way to find a domain $D$ and an object $d \in D$ and a "property" $P^D$ of objects of the domain such that:

> both $P^D$ holds of $d$ and $P^D$ does **not** hold of $d$.

---

There are proof procedures for *unsatisfiability*: see [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)).

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, proving that a set of formulas is unsatisfiable gives you something like the formal version of the engineering maxim: "Cheap. Fast. Reliable. Pick two."

Is this what you were asking?

Comment: I am looking for something more specific ahah :)